# Next.js : no response when request goes high in server-side rendering page(dynamic routing)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js, dynamic-routing

I’m using Next.js and custom server(express js) as Next.js example in GitHub.
I have a page, for example “/post/[id]”, which is using next.js dynamic routing.

The problems is, when the requests for this page goes high, response time goes high too and some times, there are no responses at all.
At this point, memory usage goes high but does not exceed maximum allowed memory.

What did I miss here?  Is there any config I should configure?

Is it a Next.js constraint?

Is it a Next.js constraint in a large environment of client requests?

**related links’s:**

[Next.js custom server express](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/custom-server-express/server.js)

[Next.js dynamic routing](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/dynamic-routing)

Answer (score 0):

Can tell about my experience:

1.check if you correctly pass NODE_ENV 
=> const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
id dev mode next.js tryong to rerender the page from time to time

2. check where you deploy chain  front -> back -> database
3. maybe you should install nginx
   it be able to return prerendered pages before next.js